# heap corruption detected after normal block error

Tags: c++

when i run this code, at the specified line the error occurs, N and N1 defines constant at the top of code. Thanks

```
double **Agf, **Ahf;////////N*N1 Matrix/////////
    Agf = new double*[N1]; for (int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)Agf[ii] = new double[N1];
    Ahf = new double*[N1]; for (int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)Ahf[ii] = new double[N1];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){ for (int j = 0; j < N1; j++){Agf[i][j] = Ahf[i][j] = 0; } }

    for (int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)
    {
    delete[] Agf[ii];
    delete[] Ahf[ii];
    }
    delete[] Agf;// error occurs here
    delete[] Ahf;
```

Comment: You are using `N1` in the `new` but looping `N` times for `N1` elements.

Comment: This doesn't look like C

Comment: First thing to do: format your code properly in order to make it readable. It's much more difficult to debug unreadable code than readable code. Look at the samples in your C++ text book, they are formatted properly.

Comment: dear @Weather Vane , because i want to create a N*N1 matrix (N rows, N1 columns), these number defined above, and at the end of function i want to delete them, where am i wrong?

Comment: you mean the last "for" ? but i tried it for N1, but again error occurs

Comment: You can see from line 4 that there are `N` rows and `N1` columns. So the row allocation should be for `N` elements to match the loops, not `N1`. I can't explain it any better than that. I suggest you use better identifier names like `ROWS` and `COLS` to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think i was wrong to define pointer, i think i should correct in this way, am i right? double **Agf; double  *Agf[row];
for (int i=0; i < row; i++)
    Agf[i] = new double[col];

Comment: You can use an online formatter like http://format.krzaq.cc/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to have a N*N1 matrix, the problem is with lines 2 and 3 of your code. you need to change them as follows:

```
Agf = new double*[N]; for (int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)Agf[ii] = new double[N1];
Ahf = new double*[N]; for (int ii = 0; ii < N; ii++)Ahf[ii] = new double[N1];
```

you need to initialize arrays with number of rows then this arrays with number of columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i found it, but i dont know why i made that mistake! Thanks again.